# Change tab style dynamically in React-Native Navigation (Wix)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I’d like to change the tab style dynamically (i.e., after the `startTabBasedApp` with the initial style was already called).
Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible now that [#2539](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/2539) is merged

api:

```
this.props.navigator.setStyle({
        tabBarButtonColor: '#0d0d0d',
        tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#ff6c33',
        tabBarBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        navigationBarColor: '#ffffff',
});
```

Comment: thanks! that’s cool!
is there a static interface as well? (i.e., something like `Navigator.setStyle`?)

Comment: Unfortunately no, in both native platforms RNN uses `appStyle` to handle theme, but this property can be set only when `start*app` is called.
This might be a nice PR candidate ;)

Answer (score -1):

Which `react-native-navigation` do you use?

You can do it, but with very specific style props, see [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-navigator?id=style-object-format)

Comment: Thanks, but this relates to the `navBar`, whereas I’m looking for the `tabBar` (dynamically)